# Formal theorems of ancient optimization problems (minimum distance from point to line; and maximum area of rectangle with a given perimeter)

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

I was reading this link over here: http://www.mitrikitti.fi/opthist.html , and came across some optimization problems from ancient history.

For instance:

- 300 BC: Euclid considers the minimal distance between a point a line
- 300 BC: Euclid proves that a square has the greatest area among the rectangles with given total length of edges

I am trying to find the official mathematical theorems that formalize these statements. For instance, I think "the minimal distance between a point and a line" is the Euclidean Distance.

However, **I am trying to find a mathematical theorem that states "a square has the greatest area among the rectangles with given total length of edges".**

Does anyone know the name of this theorem? Is it possible to find a formal statement of this theorem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We may use this formula:

$$S=\sqrt{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)-a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot \cos ^2 \frac{\theta}2}$$

Where:

$S$ is area

$p=\frac{a+b+c+d}2$

$\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$

$\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are opposite angles.

In rectangles opposite angles are $\theta_1=\theta_2=90^o$ so this formula educes to:

$$S=\sqrt{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)}$$

Now we apply this theorem that : The product of n parameters is maximum if they are equal.

Hence S is maximum if we have:

$$S^2=(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)$$

maximum. Since the sum of factors on RHS is constant:

$((p-a)+(p-b)+(p-c)+(p-d)=4p-(a+b+c+d=2p)=2p$

so area S is maximum if they are equal, that is we must have:

$$(p-a)=(p-b)=(p-c)=(p-d)$$

which gives:

$a=b=c=d$

that means the quadrilateral must be square or among rectangle with given total length of edges, the square has maximum area.